# How to implement MEF in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, dll, mef

I am trying to use MEF inside a Silverlight application. All the examples I find use this type "System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.DirectoryCatalog", but is apparently not in Silverlight, only .NET.

I am trying to get it so I drop the dll's (at runtime) in a directory the app has access to and then load those dll's using MEF.

I do understand how the Import and Export work, but I guess the issue is how do I dynamically add the xap files to my project so I can use the import and export?

Answer (score 1):

have a look at Prism : http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/
And here is a tutorial for MEF using Prism: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155835/Prism-for-Silverlight-MEF-in-Easy-Samples-Part-1-P

Comment: are you saying that I must use Prism?

Comment: I'm saying you SHOULD use prism: better use a widely-used, well-tested stable library than to implement it yourself

Answer (score 0):

The answer was as simply as I thought. I ended up using a [tutorial](http://codebetter.com/glennblock/2010/03/08/building-hello-mef-part-iv-deploymentcatalog/), which was not as straightforward as I though. Anyone that encounters this issue I suggest simplifying the tutorial version to it's smallest parts and then using it as a template